# Add class to <div> when radio button is selected

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following form:

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="options" value="option_1" id="option1" checked="checked">
  <label for="options">Option 1</label>
  <div class="first-option">
  </div>
  <input type="radio" name="options" value="option_2" id="option2">
  <label for="option">Option 2</label>
  <div class="second-option">
</form>
```

So the first option is pre-selected. I want to add a class `.option-checked` to the dive `first-option` and `second-option` when the respective radio buttons are selected. I already tried `.click(function)` but it doesn't work in this case because the first one is already pre-selected and it should automatically have `.option-checked` class with it.

Comment: Can you post the implementation that you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$("input[name='options']").click` and `switch` to implement this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("input[name='options']").click(function(){
  
  var value = $( this ).val();

                //Remove the class option-checked
  $( ".option-checked" ).removeClass( "option-checked" );
  
  switch( value ) {
   case 'option_1':
     $( ".first-option" ).addClass( "option-checked" );
    break;
   case 'option_2':
     $( ".second-option" ).addClass( "option-checked" );
    break;
  }
  
 });
});
```

```css
.option-checked {
  background-color : red;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="options" value="option_1" id="option1" checked="checked" />
  <label for="options">Option 1</label>
  <div class="first-option option-checked">first-option</div>
  <input type="radio" name="options" value="option_2" id="option2" />
  <label for="option">Option 2</label>
  <div class="second-option">second-option</div>
</form>
```

---

Another option (shorter option) also is to add a data attribute on the radio inputs for the div so that you can illiminate the `swith`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name='options']").click(function() {
    var option = $(this).data("option");
    $(".option-checked").removeClass("option-checked");
    $("." + option).addClass("option-checked");
  });
});
```

```css
.option-checked {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="options" value="option_1" id="option1" checked="checked" data-option="first-option" />
  <label for="options">Option 1</label>
  <div class="first-option option-checked">first-option</div>
  <input type="radio" name="options" value="option_2" id="option2" data-option="second-option" />
  <label for="option">Option 2</label>
  <div class="second-option">second-option</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to go through couple steps to make it happen. Initially your dig.first-option need to have the option-checked class hard coded, as the way the first radio is checked hard coded.

Then you need to create the JQuery .click() function that will remove the .option-clicked class from all the divs and then add the class to the appropriate div.

If this answer do not make the solution clear then, please create a fiddle with all the necessary code and we will make more specific help.